# AWS Ubuntu Server filling up, but why?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, storage, ubuntu-16.04

I'm currently on a free-tier AWS AmazonEC2 server with Ubuntu 16.04 installed. The main purpose is a web server running HTTP serving HTML/PHP pages and a MySQL database. The MySQL database is about 7GB large. It hasn't been inserting data for months so I don't believe the database is at fault here.

Currently Amazon is telling me my storage is at 27GB. About two days ago it was at 25GB. I haven't even touched the server in about a month and I absolutely have not been installing anything. I'm trying to find out what is taking up all this data.

I installed ncdu and switched to root, ran it and these are the results:

[image: ncdu root results]

As you can see it's absolutely nowhere near 27GB, it's at just over 13GB. So where is this other 14GB of storage coming from? How do I find this out?

I'm afraid it's going to go over the 30GB free-tier limit and I don't know what will happen or how much I will be charged (I don't know how to find this out either).

[image: AWS Stats]

Comment: Have you tried this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182077/best-way-to-free-disk-space-from-deleted-files-that-are-held-open ?

Comment: There isn't anything on /tmp that's very large at all. I also tried find / -xdev -type f -size +100M and nothing comes up greater than 100M except for my mysql database storage file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue had to do with an elastic IP being detached from a server while the server was down at one point for an amount of time.

Answer (score 2):

You're misunderstanding the email.  It has nothing to do with how much data you have stored.

It has to do with how much EBS *storage you have used* -- that is, how much you have *provisioned over time*.  EBS doesn't bill based on what you store, it bills based on how big the disks are, regardless of what you put on them.  Billing is in *gigabyte-months*.

A volume of size 1 gigabyte that *exists* for 30 days is said to "use" 1 gigabyte-month of EBS capacity.

1 gigabyte for 1 day is 1 day × 1 gb ÷ 30 days/mo =~ 0.333 gigabyte-month.

30 gigabytes for 30 days uses 30 gigabyte-months of EBS capacity.

So 30 gigabytes for 27 days would be 27 gigabyte-months, and 30 gigabytes for 25 days would be 25 gigabyte-months.

> Currently Amazon is telling me my storage is at 27GB. About two days ago it was at 25GB.

So this is normal, exactly what you'd expect if you had a single 30 GB EBS volume.  Your *usage over time* is growing because time is passing, not because usage is increasing.

AWS can't see¹ what you've stored on the volume -- they have no idea how full it is... only how large it is, which isn't a number that changes unless you resize the volume to make it physically larger.

---

¹ *can't see* may seem implausible but is true for multiple reasons, including the simple fact that they simply don't look.  An EBS volume is a block storage device.  Although typically the volumes are used for standards-based filesystems, there's no constraint on that.  They can be used in any other way that you can use a block device.  But even when used as a filesystem, the concept of "free space" is a concept only the filesystem itself understands -- not the raw, underlying device.

Comment: Read your post over a couple times and I'm honestly still a bit confused on what this "gigabyte-month" number means. Honestly might need an ELI5 summary or something. Can you provide an easy to understand example?

What is something I'm doing that could possibly lead to this number going over the free-tier limit of 30 GB? Is it likely I will be charged or no?

Comment: No, you shouldn't be charged.  EBS volumes give you an amount of *usable* storage (in gb) for a period of time.  1 GB for 1 month is 1 GB-month.  You are allowed 30 GB-months for free.  So a 30 GB volume for 1 month is free.  A 30 GB volume for 25 days has, exactly as expected, resulted in 25 GB-months of accrued usage.  If you had two of these volumes for one month, each of them would be free for the first 15 days, and not free after that.  If you had three, the free/not free cutoff would be 10 days.

Comment: My current bill says $0.03 cents now as opposed to $0.00 yesterday. Am I getting charged because there are 31 days in August?

Comment: Do you have more than 30 GB total EBS volume size?  Did you have more than 30 GB for a short time at any point?  You shouldn't be charged for 31-day months... I used the number 30 above for simplicity.

Comment: Added an image on the original post at the bottom. I shut off the server yesterday as well in case any more charges come. Defninitely seems to be 30 GB. I never changed the volume size, ever.

Comment: Okay, you'll need to drill down into the usage detail to find the explanation of the $0.03.

Comment: I think it has to do with the elastic IP. I shut down the server in fear the usage might be causing it, but apparently if its down and the elastic IP has nothing to connect to, it charges you? I'm guessing I shut the server down a while ago for a few seconds and it charged 3 cents. I'm now at 15 cents due to having shut the server down for an additional 19 hours yesterday. Strange.

Comment: Each running server gets one free EIP.  Stopped servers, extra EIPs on servers with more than one (running or not), and detached EIPs are indeed billed at $0.005 per hour.  The reasoning is to encourage efficient usage -- public IPv4 addresses are in seriously short supply.

Comment: Makes sense. The strange part to me is though that I don't recall shutting down the server for a very long amount of time to be charged 3 cents. I guess I must have at one point. All good, thank you though.